Definition of some terms
What do we mean by saying that a function exists at a point or, more generally, what is the mathematical definition of existence of a function? Also, I want to know what do we mean when we say a function is defined at a point? Are these terms (exists, defined) similar to continuity of the function at that point?

The answer to this question depends on whether you start from a formal or an informal definition of "function". If you [edit] the question to provide the definition you are working with we may be able to help. Without that information the question will be closed, or you will get a highly technical answer you may not understand. In any case the answer to the last part of your question is "no".

What do you mean by formal and informal definition?

A function $f$ "exists" at a point $a$ means that $f$ is defined at $a$, i.e. that $f(a)$ "exists". or better said: is defined. Continuity of $f$ at $a$ is a much stronger property.

So they mean the same as continuity

Existence is much weaker than continuity.

A function existing at a point $x$ means nothing more or less than $x$ is one of the points of the domain which the function, $f$, maps, and so $f(x)$ exists and is the value to which $x$ is a mapped.  If the domain of the function is $\mathbb R$ and the function is $f:x\mapsto x^2$ then the function exists at $x=2$ because $f(2)=2^2=4$ exists.  The function does not exists at $x=Harold,\ the\ elephant$ because Harold, the elephant is not an element that the function maps. "So they mean the same as continuity" No!  A function existing means it exists. Noting more.

@fleablood, i got it

In barebones term, if $A$ and $B$ are two sets, a function from $A \rightarrow B$ is a subset of $A \times B$ such that if $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ occur in that subset, then $b = c$. If $x \in A$, we say $f$ is defined at $x.$

Part of any definition of a function $f$ is its domain. That's the set of points $x$ such that the value $f(x)$ makes sense. So $f$ "exists" at $x$ just when $x$ is in the domain.
Consider the function with domain the whole real line defined by
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x \le 0 \\
1 & \text{ if } x > 0 .
\end{cases}
$$
That function "exists" for every value of $x$. If you draw its graph you will see that $f(0) = 0$ but that everywhere to the right of $0$ you have $f(x)=1$. The "jump" at $0$ means $f$ is not continuous there.
The expression $1/x$ makes sense everywhere except when $x=0$ so the function defined by $f(x) = 1/x$ has domain all of the line except $x=0$. So $f$ does not "exist" there. So of course it can't be continuous there.
$$
$$
